# Getting multiple content types all linked to same user

Tags: javascript, next.js, graphql-js, contentful

I have content types as follows:

`staff`

```
name
slug
bio...
```

`blog`

```
title
slug
Staff reference
```

`feedback`

```
feedback
Staff reference
```

A staff member can be linked to a blog (they are the author) and feedback (they are the subject of the feedback).

What I want to do is build an overview page for the staff member which combines all this in one place.

I'm currently using the getEntries function but can switch to GraphQL, just not sure how to deliver it either way.

If I use getEntries on blog or feedback and use `include:2` it returns the blog/feedback and author bio, but it's still not the full picture I want because the other (feedback/blog) is missing. I've tried chaining some together with no luck.

I have also tried GraphQL but I don't know it too well and a bit unclear on the syntax. I can get staff details but I can't figure out how to filter linked collections based on a subfield. For example, if I wanted to get the blog based on author ID I would look at blog.author.sys.id but I'm not sure how to reflect there in GraphQL.

```
query {
  staff(id:"5tEDTn3yaYntIiGoyAKR0n") {
    slug
    name
    bio {json}
    sys{id}
  }
  
  blogCollection {
    items {
      ...blogFragment
  }
  
}


fragment blogFragment on Blog {
    sys {id}
    title
    author {sys{id}}
}
```

If anyone has any suggestions on how to get all content types linked to a specific staff member I would really appreciate it. My fallback plan is to get all for each content type, store in the context and filter as appropriate but it seems a bit of a clunky way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the `linkedFrom` type if you want to use GraphQL. Below is an example query for a user associated with a blog article and comment. This query fetches all the blogs and comments made by the user.

```
query {
 user(id:"USERID") {
    name
  linkedFrom {
    commentsCollection{
      items {
        comment
      }
    }
    blogArticleCollection {
      items {
        title
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

Hope this helps :)